# ContentControl in a UserControl causes an exception

Tags: wpf, xaml

Adding a `ContentControl` with a binding into my `UserControl` causes an exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: Layout recursion reached allowed limit to avoid stack overflow: '2047'. Either the tree contains a loop or is too deep.
```

I try to switch between two views with use of content control:

```
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding}">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsListView}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource ListTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTabView}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource TabTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
```

Once the `Content={Binding}` is removed, the exception is gone. How can I trace the source of the exception? Investigation of the exception members didn't give any clue on what can cause this recursion.

**UPD**: Leaving the `ContentControl` empty (e.g. without `ListTemplate` and `TabTemplate`) doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You are excluding a lot of code that could help us help you. What does the ListTemplate look like?  The TabTemplate?  What does the code-behind look like where you define your {Binding} to the DataContext? Are you able to share your UserControl with us? If not, could you try putting the ContentControl inside a dummy UserControl to see if the same issue occurs and send us that UserControl xaml and xaml.cs file?

Comment: Yes, I understand, that information I provided is kinda not sufficient. Alas, I cannot share either complete control or a ViewModel behind (property of the company). The problem is, that both are complicated and have inheritance hierarchy, which makes things even harder to find out without debugging. However, expirienced programmers may have ideas on typical sources of this type of error. But I'll add some answers to your questions into my post.

Comment: I am an experienced WPF programmer, and I can tell you that this type of error is not typical.  I understand the concerns about company IP, so I thought I'd let you decide what more you could share.  My initial eyeball test is telling me that you are incorrectly using the Content property of the ContentControl.  Typically that property would be used to define more UIElements, not a ViewModel binding.  But that's as far as I can figure out without more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The Problem

`ContentControl` will attempt to show whatever the value of it's `Content` property is using a [`ContentPresenter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter). The MSDN doc I've linked describes the full logic that the `ContentPresenter` uses in determining how to best display the content it's been given, but these are the two most relevant points:

First it will try this:

> - If the `ContentTemplate` property on the `ContentPresenter` is set, the `ContentPresenter` applies that `DataTemplate` to the `Content` property and the resulting `UIElement` and its child elements, if any, are displayed.

Later on, if the above has failed (meaning `ContentTemplate` was not set), it will try this:

> - If `Content` is a `UIElement` object, the `UIElement` is displayed. If the `UIElement` already has a parent, an exception occurs.

When you first load the `ContentControl`, `Content="{Binding}"` sets `Content` to `DataContext`, which I'm assuming is your `UserControl`. Your `Style` has triggers that set `ContentTemplate` *conditionally*. This means there will be some moments when `ContentTemplate` is *not set*, so `ContentPresenter` will default to trying to display `Content`, which is a `UIElement`, as one of it's children.

So the `ContentPresenter` will try to display the entire `UserControl` as it's child, no problem- except part of that new "child" is itself, so to render than inner version of itself, it needs to display the `Content` property. And it continues like this in an infinite, recursive loop of `ContentControl`s trying to display themselves within themselves until a limit is reached and WPF bails and throws an exception.

## The Solution

1. **Always have a `ContentTemplate`**.
   You'll need to have some sort of default `ContentTemplate` for the `ContentControl` to show if none of the triggers activate.
2. **Use `ContentPresenter` directly instead of `ContentControl`**
   I'm not actually sure why this the case, but even after providing a default `ContentTemplate`, it still wouldn't work. It probably has something to do with the internal workings of `ContentControl`. However, switching out the `ContentControl` for a `ContentPresenter` fixes everything.

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding}">
    <ContentPresenter.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <!--"Default" template that will be used if none of the triggers are active-->
                    <DataTemplate>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
                    
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsListView}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource ListTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTabView}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource TabTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentPresenter.Style>
</ContentPresenter>
```